# How I can insert into a grid spatial object in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with points with x y coordinate, I want to create a grid, and insert this points into de the grid, to visualize better the information of the points.

I have create the grid (I am not sure if is the best way to do it):

```
# load some spatial data. Administrative Boundary
porto <- getData('GADM', country = 'Portugal', level = 2)
porto$NAME_1
porto <- porto[porto$NAME_2 == "Porto", ]


# check the CRS to know which map units are used
proj4string(porto)
# "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

# Create a grid of points within the bbox of the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
# colorado with decimal degrees as map units
grid <- makegrid(porto, cellsize = 0.003) # cellsize in map units!

# grid is a data.frame. To change it to a spatial data set we have to
grid <- SpatialPoints(grid, proj4string = CRS(proj4string(porto)))

portoWithin <- SpatialPixels(grid, proj4string = CRS(proj4string(porto)))

plot(porto)
plot(portoWithin, add = T)
```

I would like to create a heat map with the grid to see in whith area concentrates more points.

Comment: I think [this page](http://www.robert-hickman.eu/post/getis-ord-heatmaps-tutorial/) can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say your dataset with points with x y coordinate is this:

```
#### Data you have that will change the grid values #########
x = c(-8.64, -8.60, -8.65)
y = c(41.14, 41.16, 41.17)
val = c(21,10,30)

df =data.frame(x,y,val)

# Converting to a Spatial Points Data Frame so you can keep the value that you will change within the Grid
points = SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = df[,1:2],df)
```

Now that you have your Spatial Point loaded in with the Values that will change your Grid. All you have to do is convert your grid to a Raster, Here is all of your code, with some of my work below it, with comments:

```
# load some spatial data. Administrative Boundary
porto <- getData('GADM', country = 'Portugal', level = 2)
porto$NAME_1
porto <- porto[porto$NAME_2 == "Porto", ]


# check the CRS to know which map units are used
proj4string(porto)
# "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

# Create a grid of points within the bbox of the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
# colorado with decimal degrees as map units
grid <- makegrid(porto, cellsize = 0.003) # cellsize in map units!

# grid is a data.frame. To change it to a spatial data set we have to
grid <- SpatialPoints(grid, proj4string = CRS(proj4string(porto)))

portoWithin <- SpatialPixels(grid, proj4string = CRS(proj4string(porto)))

#### Converting the GRID to a Raster
ras_portoWithin <- raster(portoWithin)

## Assigning temporary values to the raster
values(ras_portoWithin) <- 0

## Using the Spatial point file created above (the one with your values) to replace the values of the raster
r1 <- ras_portoWithin
r1[points] <- points$val
plot(r1)
```

[image]

You now have your Grid, with the values given by your points!

Let me know if this helps!